# How to define an enumeration with ember-model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

In my ember-model model I need to set a String attribute from an enumeration.
Is it possible with ember-model?

By Example I would like to have a Book model:

```
App.Book({
    id: Ember.attr(),
    title: Ember.attr( 'String' ),
    author: Ember.attr( 'String' ),
    status: App.BookStatus
});
```

and `App.Book.Status` as an enum with 3 possible values `"FREE", "BORROW", "LOST"` and use it:

```
var myBook = App.Book.create({
    title:'myBook', 
    author:'fred', 
    status: App.BookStatus.FREE
})
```

I need the equivalent to the Java Enum feature

```
public enum BookStatus {
    FREE, BORROW, LOST 
}

class Book {
    BookStatus bookStatus;
}

Book bookInstance = new Book();
bookInstance.bookStatus=BookStatus.LOST;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the docs:

> In Ember.js, an Enumerable is any object that contains a number of child objects, and which allows you to work with those children using the Ember.Enumerable API.

So for example:

```
var players = ["Alex", "Paul", "Tom"];

players.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log('Player %@: %@'.fmt(index+1, item));
});
```

Would output:

```
// Player 1: Alex
// Player 2: Paul
// Player 3: Tom
```

**To make your own custom class enumerable, you need two items:**

To make your own enumerable class/object in ember you could use the [`Ember.Enumerable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) mixin and follow this two requirements:

- You must have a `length` property. This property should change whenever the number of items in your enumerable object changes. If you using this with an [`Ember.Object`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) subclass, you should be sure to change the `length` property using the built-in `set()` method.
- If you must implement `nextObject()`.

Once you have these two methods implemented, apply the [`Ember.Enumerable`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) mixin to your class and you will be able to enumerate the contents of your object like any other collection.

Pseudo code:

```
App.MyEnumObject = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Enumerable, {
  length: 0,
  nextObject: function() {
    //return the next object of the enumeration
  }
  //more methods and properties
});
```

See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/) for more info on enumerable in ember.

Hope it helps.

### Edit

Since we are using javascript, what you are trying to do could be done in a much simpler way. For example:

```
App.bookStatus = {
  FREE: "FREE",
  BORROW: "BORROW",
  LOST: "LOST"
}
  
var myBook = App.Book.create({id: 1, title: 'myBook', author: 'fred', status: App.bookStatus.FREE})
```

Comment: I've updated my question with more details to be certain you get the right understanding. Is your answer still exact with my more detailed question ?

Comment: @fvisticot, please see my updated answer, I didn't realize that what you where trying to do could be achieved in a much simpler way since this is javascript land :)

Comment: Not sure what the question originally asked, but most of this answer is about the Enumberable API, which serves a fairly different purpose than Enums (Enumerations) in Java, C etc.

Answer (score 0):

For simple enum's in Ember, just using a simple JavaScript object, as shown at the bottom of [@intuitivepixel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064045/260491) would suffice, but you can get [a bit more functional, Ember-style enums with ember-computed-enum](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-computed-enum).

It allows getting and setting by more JavaScript-style-friendly names:

```
myBook.get('status');  // -> 'free'
myBook.set('status', 'lost');
myBook.get('status');  // -> 'lost'
myBook.save();  // -> saves `status: "LOST"` to the server
```

but also adds `enumNameIsValue` properties that are particularly useful in templates:

```
myBook.get('statusIsLost');  // -> true
myBook.get('statusIsFree');  // -> false
```

Install with `ember install ember-computed-enum`, then usage is pretty simple

Assuming your model looks something like:

```
// app/models/book.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  statusCode: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Where `statusCode` is returned from the server as one of `"FREE"`, `"BORROW"`, or `"LOST"`

You would add a [mixin-style Ember enum](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-computed-enum#as-a-mixin-with-enumnameisvalue-properties) like this:

```
// app/models/book.js

import DS from 'ember-data';
import { computedEnumMixin } from 'ember-computed-enum';

BOOK_STATUS_ENUM = {
  free: "FREE",
  borrow: "BORROW",
  lost: "LOST"
};

export default DS.Model.extend(
  computedEnumMixin('status', 'statusCode', BOOK_STATUS_ENUM),
  {
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.attr('string'),
  statusCode: DS.attr('string')
});
```

If you're not able to change the name of the `status` field to `statusCode` in the API, and still want to use the name `status` to access the value within your code, you can [remap the model field name using a serializer](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-computed-enum/#re-using-the-existing-attribute-name):

```
// app/serializers/book.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    statusCode: 'status'  // map the API's "status" field to the "statusCode" field on the model
  }
});
```

Note: I've made the examples to reflect current (Feb 2017) ember-cli conventions, rather than the older globals style of the question

Comment: As a small correction, I think your last codeblock should actually say `computedEnumMixin('statusCode', 'status', BOOK_STATUS_ENUM),`, and it should be `status: DS.attr('string')`. As it is, the serialization of the model you've presented would be slightly different than OP's original `App.Book`, which had a `.status` attribute, not a `.statusCode` attribute.

Comment: @Belden thanks for the note. Instead of just flipping `status` and `statusCode`, I've added a section on [remapping the field name with a serializer](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/ember-computed-enum/#re-using-the-existing-attribute-name) so the API can remain unchanged, while still accessing a `status` field on the model object. Does that address the concern you had?

Comment: your change looks good :D